# Evaluate $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\sin[a\ln(1-x)]}{\ln(1-x)}\cdot x\mathrm dx$

Tags: definite-integrals

How do we evaluate

$$I=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\sin[a\ln(1-x)]}{\ln(1-x)}\cdot x\mathrm dx$$

Making a sub: $u=\ln(1-x)$ this lead to a messy integral.

I believe the closed form for $I=\arctan\left(\frac{a}{a^2+2}\right)$, how to shows it, I am not sure. We leaves it to the expert!

Comment: Try to  differentiate with respect to $a$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let  $$I(a)=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\sin[a\ln(1-x)]}{\ln(1-x)}\cdot x\mathrm dx$$
Then $$\begin{split}
I^\prime(a)&=\int_0^1x\cos[a\ln(1-x)]dx\\
&=\int_{0}^{+\infty}(1-e^{-t})\cos(-at)e^{-t}dt \,\,\,\left(\text{via }t=-\ln(1-x)\right)\\
&=\int_0^{+\infty}(e^{-t}-e^{-2t})\frac{e^{iat}+e^{-iat}}2dt\\
&=\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{e^{(ia-1)t}+e^{-(ia+1)t}-e^{(ia-2)t}-e^{-(ia+2)t}}{2}dt\\
&=\frac 1 2 \left(\frac{1}{1-ia} +  \frac{1}{1+ia} -\frac{1}{2-ia} - \frac{1}{2+ia}\right)\\
&=\frac  1 {1+a^2}-\frac{2}{a^2+4}
\end{split}$$
Note that $I(0)=0$ and integrate:
$$I(a)=\arctan(a)-\arctan(\frac a 2)$$
which can be simplified into $$\boxed{I(a)=\arctan\left(\frac{a}{a^2+2}\right)}$$

Answer (score 0):

**By Feynman’s Integration Technique**

First of all, letting $ x\mapsto 1-x$ transforms the integral into
$$
I(a)=\int_0^1 \frac{\sin (a \ln x)}{\ln x}(1-x) d x
$$
Differentiating $I(a)$ w.r.t. $a$ yields
$$
I^{\prime}(a)=\int_0^1(1-x) \cos (a \ln x) d x
$$
Putting $y=-\ln x$ gives
$$
\begin{aligned}
I^{\prime}(a) & =\int_0^{\infty} e^{-y}\left(1-e^{-y}\right) \cos (a y) d y \\
& =\int_0^{\infty} e^{-y} \cos (a y) d y-\int_0^{\infty} e^{-2 y} \cos (a y) d y \\
& =\frac{1}{a^2+1}-\frac{2}{a^2+4}
\end{aligned}
$$

Integrating back, we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^1 \frac{\sin [a \ln (1-x)]}{\ln (1-x)} \cdot x d x & =\int_0^a\left(\frac{1}{x^2+1}-\frac{2}{x^2+4}\right) d x \\
& =\tan ^{-1} a-\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{a}{2}\right) \\
& =\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{a}{a^2+2}\right)
\end{aligned}
$$

Answer (score 0):

**By Double integral**

Letting $1-x=e^{-y}$ transforms the integral into
$$
\begin{aligned}
I & =-\int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{-y}-e^{-2 y}}{y} \sin (a y) d y \\
& =\int_0^{\infty}\left[\int_1^2 e^{-t y} d t \cdot \sin (a y)\right] d y \\
& =\int_1^2\left[\int_0^{\infty} e^{-t y} \sin (a y) d y\right] d t \\
& =\int_1^2 \frac{a}{a^2+t^2} d t \\
& =\left[\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{t}{a}\right)\right]_1^2 \\
& =\tan ^{-1} \frac{2}{a}-\tan ^{-1} \frac{1}{a} \\
& =\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{a}{a^2+2}\right)
\end{aligned}
$$